# Форматирование / Консоль

Tags: c++

Мне необходимо выводить слово непосредственно после введенной информации по типу:

> > Input numer: _

---

> > Input numer: 9_ * энтер *

---

> > Input numer: 9 seconds

Однако сколько я не перерыл форумов - или я не правильно формулирую запрос, или это просто невозможно.

Comment: Чисто *стандартными* средствами не получится.

Comment: @Cixo Решил вашу задачу, [создал мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228319/267338) для Windows/Linux/MacOS, используя не стандартные С++ средства, а специфичные для разных операционных систем, т.к. как сказал Harry стандартных средств С++ библиотеки вроде бы нет.

Answer (score 2):

Стандартными С++ средствами вроде не решишь задачу, но есть понятие [управляющие ANSI последовательности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI) (более информативна [английская вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)) которые позволяют в ANSI консоле делать дополнительные красивые вещи, например двигать курсор, или раскрашивать текст.

По умолчанию большинство Linux/MacOS консолей поддерживают эти ANSI-последовательности. Но к сожалению Windows по умолчанию нет, и требует дополнительных настроек консоли через WinApi функции, что я и делаю в следующем коде. Следующий код будет работать как в Windows так и в Linux/MacOS.

Следующий код можно сократить под Linux/MacOS убрав всё между `#ifdef _WIN32` и соотвествующим `#endif`.

В следующем коде ANSI последовательность `"\x1b[1A"` переводит курсор на одну строку вверх, если надо на 6 строк то будет последовательность `"\x1b[6A"` (видно где 6 вставил?). Вторая последовательность `"\x1b[17C"`, она смещает курсор на 17 позиций вправо.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
inline bool WinAnsiConsoleEnable(int stdout_or_stderr = 0) {
    #ifndef ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING
        #define ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING 0x0004
    #endif
    DWORD outMode = 0;
    HANDLE stdoutHandle = GetStdHandle(stdout_or_stderr == 0 ?
        STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE : stdout_or_stderr == 1 ? STD_ERROR_HANDLE : 0);
    if (stdoutHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return false;
    if (!GetConsoleMode(stdoutHandle, &outMode))
        return false;
    // Enable ANSI escape codes
    outMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
    if (!SetConsoleMode(stdoutHandle, outMode))
        return false;
    return true;
}
#endif // _WIN32

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    #ifdef _WIN32
        SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
        if (!WinAnsiConsoleEnable()) {
            std::cout << "Error enabling Win ansi console!" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    #endif
    std::cout << "Input number: ";
    int n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;
    // Move 1 line up
    std::cout << "\x1b[1A";
    // Move 17 chars to right
    std::cout << "\x1b[17C";
    // Output tail
    std::cout << "seconds" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Next line..." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Input number: 9  seconds
Next line...
```

---

Ниже привожу решение без ANSI-последовательности, решение специфичное только для Windows (следующий код в Linux/MacOS не заработает), т.к. использует WinApi функции перемещения курсора.

```
#include <windows.h>

inline bool WinMoveCursor(int offx, int offy) {
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO cbsi = {};
    if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &cbsi))
        return false;
    COORD coord = cbsi.dwCursorPosition;
    coord.X += offx;
    coord.Y += offy;
    if (!SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, coord))
        return false;
    return true;
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
    std::cout << "Input number: ";
    int n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;
    if (!WinMoveCursor(+17, -1)) {
        std::cout << "Error moving Win cursor!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    // Output tail
    std::cout << "seconds" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Next line..." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Input number: 9  seconds
Next line...
```